# OEL 8.3 SSSD AD Login issue

Tags: linux, active-directory, sssd, centos8

I am running Oracle Enterprise LINUX 8.3 . I am able to join my AD domain with an admin account but when I try to login to the server using the same credentials that I used to join the server to the AD I am getting incorrect password.

```
Jun 24 17:30:57 rdc-stg-master1 sshd[1896]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=172.28.236.43 user=ncrcoldpc@rdc.com
Jun 24 17:30:57 rdc-stg-master1 sshd[1896]: pam_sss(sshd:auth): received for user ncc@dc.com: 4 (System error)
Jun 24 17:30:59 rdc-stg-master1 sshd[1896]: Failed password for ncc@dc.com from 172.28.236.43 port 55884 ssh2
Jun 24 17:31:02 rdc-stg-master1 sshd[1896]: Connection closed by authenticating user ncrcoldpc@rdc.com 172.28.236.43 port 55884 [preauth]
```

Not sure how I can join the domain successfully but then it tells me incorrect password when trying to SSH.

here is my sssd.conf

```
[root@rdc-stg-master1 sssd]# more sssd.conf

[sssd]
domains = DC.com
config_file_version = 2
services = nss, pam

[domain/DC.com]
ad_domain = DC.com
krb5_realm = RDC.COM
realmd_tags = manages-system joined-with-adcli
cache_credentials = True
id_provider = ad
krb5_store_password_if_offline = True
default_shell = /bin/bash
ldap_id_mapping = True
use_fully_qualified_names = True
fallback_homedir = /home/%u@%d
access_provider = ad
[root@rdc-stg-master1 sssd]#

[root@rdc-stg-master1 sssd]# nslookup dc.com
Server:         172.28.17.166
Address:        172.28.17.166#53

Name:   dc.com
Address: 172.28.17.167
Name:   dc.com
Address: 172.28.17.166
```

LOG file:

```
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): Could not resolve address for this machine, error [5]: Input/output error, resolver returned: [11]: Could not contact DNS servers
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [nsupdate_get_addrs_done] (0x0040): nsupdate_get_addrs_done failed: [5]: [Input/output error]
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [sdap_dyndns_dns_addrs_done] (0x0040): Could not receive list of current addresses [5]: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [ad_dyndns_sdap_update_done] (0x0040): Dynamic DNS update failed [5]: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [be_ptask_done] (0x0040): Task [Dyndns update]: failed with [5]
: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [resolv_gethostbyname_done] (0x0040): querying hosts database failed [5]: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [sdap_sudo_get_hostnames_done] (0x0040): Could not resolve fqdn for this machine, error [5]: Input/output error, resolver returned: [11]: Could not contact DNS servers
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [sdap_sudo_get_hostinfo_done] (0x0020): Unable to retrieve hostnames [5]: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:48): [be[DC.com]] [sdap_sudo_refresh_hostinfo_done] (0x0040): Unable to retrieve
host information, host filter will be disabled [5]: Input/output error
(2021-06-24 17:30:52): [be[DC.com]] [write_krb5info_file_from_fo_server] (0x0020): There is no server that can be written into kdc info file.
```

Any ideas?